# Partial Lenses: Group array of objects by property, use prop value as key

Tags: javascript, lenses, partial-lenses

I have an array of objects like this:

```
[
  { name: "Group 1", value: "Foo" },
  { name: "Group 2", value: "Bar" },
  { name: "Group 1", value: "Baz" }
]
```

I'd like to use [Partial Lenses](https://github.com/calmm-js/partial.lenses) library to transform these groups to keys of an object with corresponding group's items, like this:

```
{
  "Group 1": [
    { name: "Group 1", value: "Foo" },
    { name: "Group 1", value: "Baz" }
  ],
  "Group 2": [
    { name: "Group 2", value: "Bar" }
  ]
}
```

My current approach is like this, assuming I have the source data in a variable called `data`:

```
const grouped = L.collect([L.groupBy('name'), L.entries], data)
const setKey = [L.elems, 0]
const getName = [L.elems, 1, 0, 'name']
const correctPairs = L.disperse(setKey, L.collectTotal(getName, grouped), grouped)
L.get(L.inverse(L.keyed), correctPairs)
```

I don't like that I need to use the `grouped` and `correctPairs` variables to hold data, as I probably should be able to do the transformation directly in the composition. Could you help me to compose the same functionality in a more meaningful way?

Here's a [Partial Lenses Playground](https://calmm-js.github.io/partial.lenses/playground.html#MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBtAUAbxmBAWwFMAuGAIgHEAnEAVwAcYBGCgGhgDcEAbespQBiIEBRgBfdrnxFB1OkxgAmDtz4DyFAEIIa4qTIIkttBszace-eboBeBrAF0sWUJFgBzRY2Jw0MAAyAHSgvLzEwFAAFBgh3ubaAJ7RAOTGxKkAlJwhxGBQNACWxBBOnIjIWW7g0DAQxFAA0sRJAXHBxBGEEJwADC7udZ6NAHJy7Xndvaz9nOlyqYO1sKA0NJFQAAoIRTQQASFwRRC++8TRDc2tuaEg4ZsAKiDIvNEjUOMknAlMfjkwX6+ODVLDxRrREJFMBcYjnSHBADWrX+nDWGyiOz2EFBQA) with the above code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the goal is to actually create an isomorphism through which one can
view such an array as an object of arrays and also perform updates.  Like a
bidirectional version of e.g. Ramda's
[`R.groupBy`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#groupBy) function.

Indeed, one approach would be to just use Ramda's
[`R.groupBy`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#groupBy) to implement a new primitive
isomorphism using [`L.iso`](https://github.com/calmm-js/partial.lenses/#l-iso).
Something like this:

```
const objectBy = keyL => L.iso(
  R.cond([[R.is(Array), R.groupBy(L.get(keyL))]]),
  R.cond([[R.is(Object), L.collect([L.values, L.elems])]])
)
```

The conditionals are needed to allow for the possibility that the data is not of
the expected type and to map the result to `undefined` in case it isn't.

Here is [a playground with the above Ramda based
`objectBy`](https://calmm-js.github.io/partial.lenses/playground.html#MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBtAUAbxmBAWwFMAuGAIgHEAnEAVwAcYBGCgGhgDcEAbespQBiIEBRgBfdrnxFB1OkxgAmDtz4DyFAEIIa4qTIIkttBszace-eboBeBrAF0sWUJFggARgCtiwKG0ATzQYAGtiIIAZNAA+GCiAOgBLCBAACiwAJUT3OHSMDBzU9IBBGhoEIIBKThyAc0VGYPSk+uIodIjo6uqnJ1rs3PB8wuKIdIB5X38oWoTh3l5ZgqTrAQhOJOJlwggB-uqsI7dwaBhUkFDvPwCWgHJjYnuT3hB69IX2zsvORGRqjAjm8Pl8OgBJMBcYg0CDEdK-ME-NJ-JAIXpArAgz5JOGdDCI+5mJQse6cAAMnHu62eTipkxAADMyfA0YDge8cYkaMRCCBoQVCcTmMoWeS6ayAUCgA)
implementation.

Using only the current version of Partial Lenses, one way to compose a similar
`objectBy` combinator would be as follows:

```
const objectBy = keyL => [
  L.groupBy(keyL),
  L.array(L.unzipWith1(L.iso(x => [L.get(keyL, x), x], L.get(1)))),
  L.inverse(L.keyed)
]
```

Perhaps the interesting part in the above is the middle part that converts an
array of arrays into an array of key-array pairs (or the other way around).
[`L.unzipWith1`](https://github.com/calmm-js/partial.lenses/#l-unzipWith1)
checks that all the keys within a group match, and if they don't, that group
will be mapped to `undefined` and filtered out by
[`L.array`](https://github.com/calmm-js/partial.lenses/#l-array).  If desired,
it is possible to get stricter behaviour by using
[`L.arrays`](https://github.com/calmm-js/partial.lenses/#l-arrays).

Here is [a playground with the above composed
`objectBy`](https://calmm-js.github.io/partial.lenses/playground.html#MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBtAUAbxmBAWwFMAuGAIgHEAnEAVwAcYBGCgGhgDcEAbespQBiIEBRgBfdrnxFB1OkxgAmDtz4DyFAEIIa4qTIIkttBszace-eboBeBrAF0sWUJFggARgCtiwKG0ATzQYAGtiIIAZNAA+TCwogDoAc0VGYIAKCOiASmlkvRoEIMzk+jA7AEtGAHUqqAALFjKkqogQTIAPOMxklOIobMiozi78mC6nTn7BzJZcxfzEtrAuYhoIYlac4jhc51d3aBh2kFDvPwCsgHJjYhuDrF4QFMyYWaGzzkRkXJgDi83h9UoMAJJrDZbTLfEEDL4dH5IBCLAHPV7vZJbIYYWE3MxKFg3TgABk4N2sAhu0xgNwA8iAAGbE+DI-6AjEgmjEQggdaZXGI2kE5jKFkkmm-FEAoA)
implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.reduce](http://**)

```js
let arr = [{ name: "Group 1", value: "Foo" },{ name: "Group 2", value: "Bar" },{ name: "Group 1", value: "Baz" }];

let obj = arr.reduce((a,c) => Object.assign(a, {[c.name]: (a[c.name] || []).concat(c)}), {});
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: I'm getting a undefined when executing your code {
  "Group 1": [    [      undefined,      {        "name": "Group 1",[....]

Comment: Seems like one too many square brackets around `a[c.name]`. Remove them and it works fine 

Comment: @DavidLemon - I have updated the answer. Please check.

Comment: @jehna1 - Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any library, use a generic function that returns a reducer, that way you can use to group any collection with any key. In the example below I used this to group by name, but also by value.

```js
const groupBy = key => (result,current) => {
  let item = Object.assign({},current);
  // optional
  // delete item[key];
  if (typeof result[current[key]] == 'undefined'){
    result[current[key]] = [item];
  }else{
    result[current[key]].push(item);
  }
  return result;
};

const data = [{ name: "Group 1", value: "Foo" },{ name: "Group 2", value: "Bar" },{ name: "Group 1", value: "Baz" }];

const grouped = data.reduce(groupBy('name'),{});
console.log(grouped);
const groupedByValue = data.reduce(groupBy('value'),{});
console.log(groupedByValue);
```

Comment: Good approach! I do like that one doesn't use unnecessary libraries when there isn't a need for one. For this kind of problem it's good to have simple, readable code like yours to solve a problem. For my case I wanted to use partial lenses since I'll need to have quite a bunch of other object mangling too which is pretty straightforward with a tool like partial lenses (so this was just the hardest problem I had, isolated from other code).